# lightning:recordViewForm not displaying Account Name

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.accountName}" objectApiName="Account">
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
```

to display the account name - what is strange is that name itself is not being displayed, but every other field on the Account object works, so the ID is being passed correctly. Phone, Address, custom fields all work, but Name not, how so? Is this a known Salesforce issue? If I create a custom formula field to replicate account name and output that in the outputField, that works, but it feels redundant to do..

Is it possible that there are some conflicting record types?

Comment: Can you ensure the Name field is a part of your page (record detail) layouts? There is one behavior where fields do not show up when it's not referenced in page layouts.

Comment: Maybe use a different attribute name? `v.accountName` might cause a name collision perhaps. How about just `v.accountId`?

Comment: maybe this is a permission issue - does the user's profile have permission to view this field?

Comment: Yeah.. I'm Sys Admin and I can't see it. The field does exist on the page layout